# Is it possible to style search-selection in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, selection

In Firefox, I can search for text using either

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> [normal search]
- <kbd>/</kbd> [quick search]
- <kbd>'</kbd> [quick search, links only]

I can style user-selected text / links using

- `a:focus`
- `a:active`
- `::-moz-selection`

However

- the first two seem to apply only to user-selected/focused/activated links (by mouse, or <kbd>TAB</kbd>-navigating).
- `::-moz-selection` seems to be applied only to the text I manually selected, not the text that is selected due to incremental search. The incremental search match is highlighted by Firefox in the greenish color.
- when I search only in links (<kbd>'</kbd>), the searched part is being highlighted by Firefox in the same greenish color; moreover, the whole link gets outline; when the quick find disappears (~5 secs), the whole link gets `:focus` style applied -- not before that.

See the screenshot:

[image: Firefox search-selection highlight]

Is there any CSS pseudoclass to allow styling of selection **that resulted from the search**, not the user hand-selection?

Comment: You mean like you see in the [Google Search Terms](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-tools-highlight-google-search-terms-target-page/) technique?

Comment: No, I mean search **within browser** (CTRL-F), not from Google :) Browser-side. Have you taken a look at the screenshot?

Comment: I said *like*, yes I've seen the screenshot. What the Google Search Terms technique does is use GET values passed to the page and an in-page script to automate wrapping the terms in markup with a class that highlights the terms on the page. Is *this* what you are after?

Comment: Yep, this is _like_ I want it to be. But while it's pretty easy to extract stuff from URL, how could you, inside JS, intercept what has been typed in CTRL-F field in Firefox? I guess you can't do this, as it's internal browser stuff. Anyway, the way how Firefox highlights searched term suggests that internally it has some pseudoclass/whatever to achieve the green highlight, the question is, whether this pseudoclass is exposed in the CSS API (I don't see other solution; well, perhaps some add-on code could intercept it / wrap in some markup, but it's an overkill).

Comment: Use `onkeypress` to capture and prevent `'` and/or `CTRL+F` from being pressed and replace it with your own search tool technique. There's probably a library or plugin out there for doing that.

Comment: Hmm that can be the solution, but requires a bit of effort to have  good usability. However, 1) I need it in fact only for my own purposes (Stylish), 2) disabling `CTRL+F` for the users on a real site is the good way to reduce the number of your visitors ;) (unless it ultimately mimicks the real behavior of the browser). I don't like to engage JS in this kind of things until it's totally necessary.

Comment: Since you're asking the question, your particular usage, requirements or needs are, of course, your own. If you want to style it personally (ie, your own browser only), you might be able to do so with a custom Persona. If you want to manipulate your user's browser's setting, I suspect that may be a problem since it appears to be part of the chrome and possibly too low-level to get to. If you want a custom colorized in-page search, then you'll probably need a scripted approach.

Comment: Actually, Personas don't appear to give that much control. Maybe a custom theme. You can [download a theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/157613/ft_deepdark-3.3.5-fx-windows.jar?src=cb-dl-users) and see what you find.

Comment: This [mozillazine forum post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1331845) at least suggests which styles cover the find highlight coloring, although this does not mean you can override it on another browser (as it's part of the chrome).

Comment: Setting `ui.textSelectBackgroundAttention` in `about:config` works for me. You can post it as an answer I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [mozillazine forum post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1331845), you can go to `about:config` and add one of the following to style different `ui.text*` settings on the browser chrome:

```
ui.textSelectBackground
ui.textSelectBackgroundAttention
ui.textSelectBackgroundDisabled
ui.textSelectForeground
ui.textBackground
ui.textForeground
ui.textHighlightBackground
ui.textHighlightForeground
```

Comment: Note that this is only for yourself, you cannot make this change global for the rest of your users on your site.

Comment: As @Truth suggests, `about:config` and the browser chrome are internal to the Firefox browser.

Comment: Sure. I only needed it for my own, so it's ok. I think there's no CSS property for this and probably there won't be any for a long time, or ever.