# Chrome / FF Search Results Highlight Styling

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, styles, highlight

I have been researching this topic for a while now but could not find anything relevant.

Is there a way to override the default styles in Chrome / FF for the highlighted search results ? By that I mean the **search results you obtain by doing cmd / ctrl + f and typing a search term**.

The default style is *yellow / orange for Chrome, and green for FF*.

I tried using the **::selection** pseudo selector, but this can only style text that is manually highlighted by the end user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, this isn't something that you can change for users of the site, but you can can definitely change it for yourself in Firefox, but I am a bit unsure about Chrome.

You just have to type in `about:config` in the address bar.  From there, if it isn't already in the list, add the property `ui.textSelectBackgroundAttention` and then add whatever color you want ad the value.

The following answer gives more properties to add.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11593406/2236808